# Monitor Network Printers

Tags: printer

I have a printer directly connected to LAN. I need to monitor which IP printed how many pages on that printer.I have a HP Laserjet MFP M521dn printer. Till now I have dumped the printer log in a remote log server but the logs doesn't give any info about IP or hostname from which the print request was sent.I've also tried to configure savapage and Windows 2003 radius but I am stuck there too. I can't use papercut because the license fees is too high. Need help

Comment: I think most more complex accounting is usually done by installing a print server rather than allowing users to print directly to the network printer, but I'm by no means a specialist in that area.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use snmp protocol if your printer supports it.
By example see discussion on [cacti forum](http://forums.cacti.net/about12970.html)

Comment: Ok this is more printer specific, I enabled snmp on this printer but I am not getting any output when I am doing snmpwalk on the printer. Also nmap on printer showed  port 161 closed

Comment: Check snmp version on printer. Restart printer by power reset.